# ASCII characters in ElasticSearch with Tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, elasticsearch

I have a website in Brazilian portuguese. I'm using Elasticsearch to run our site search.

When the visitors search from our site, everything works, but codebasehq give some exceptions (errors) like this: Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed

```
nested: JsonParseException[Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x72\n at [Source: [B@42dcdefd; line: 1, column: 46]]; }]","status":500}
```

These errors only came from URLs that I don't know where are these links, for example:

```
?q=Acess%F3rios (error)
?q=Acessórios (ok)
?q=Acess%C3%B3rios (ok)
```

I don't know how to fix this error, I'm trying to stop to generate that errors in codebasehq.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be coming from Elasticsearch, which trips on the invalid JSON received.

In general, Tire handles accented characters in searches just fine:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'tire'

s = Tire.search do
  query { string 'Žluťoučký' }
end

p s.results
```

You should enable the Tire logging with:

```
Tire.configure { logger STDERR, level: "debug" }
```

or with the [Rails logger](https://github.com/karmi/tire-contrib/blob/master/lib/tire/rails/logger.rb), to find the offending JSON, debug it, and possibly post more information here.

Comment: In my website is ok, accented characters works. but I don't know how Google is crawling these link if these kind of characters doesn't exist in my app. In some situation Google must convert these characters. I don't know.

Comment: @OsnyNetto What kind of query are you using, the `string` query? What if you choose the `match` query? Can you post the full query?